# Laravel routing pattern similar to Yii

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, routes

I am new to Laravel and by reading a bit its documentation, it seems that for each new page or `url` I need to define a route in the `web.php` file. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So, my question is... Is there a way to create a pattern as in `YII framework` or `.NET framework` to manage all routes (or most of them) at once by using something like:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Comment: The framework doesn't provide a way to do this currently.

Comment: Thanks @FatBoyXPC this is bad news to me but definitely is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly like Yii or .net but you can declare multiple routes in one line using Resource Controllers.

> Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code. For example, you may wish to create a controller that handles all HTTP requests for "photos" stored by your application.

You can do so by `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');`

[Read more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: It is precisely what I want to avoid doing: to declare multiple routes.

Comment: Oh sorry, I presumed that you just needed concise method of handing routes.
My bad.
I would second FatBoyXPC's comment that _The framework doesn't provide a way to do this currently._